# Make readonly fields unclickable

Tags: javascript, php, html

In my form i am using readonly fields.

How to make this readonly fields unclickable I don't want to use disabled fields, just make readonly fields unclickable any one have idea plz share.

Comment: Unclickable how exactly ?

Comment: What do you mean by "unclickable"? Do you mean that you don't want the user to be able to focus the element, then that is the default behavior for inputs with the readonly attribute.

Comment: the fields are readonly but when ever i click on field it focuses(clickable) but not editable it must not be clickable @adeneo,@rioc0719

Comment: That's not happening in my browser, a readonly input is not clickable, nor focusable, but the text can be highlighted and copied, is that what you want to avoid ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jhh5mr9x/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I searched and i found the solution here it is.

```
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="#unclickable" />
<script>
  $("#unclickable").focus(function(){
  $(this).blur(); 
  });
</script>
```

Comment: There is really no need for jQuery, the same can be done way faster using plain Javascript.

Comment: See the upvoted answer from Panther for a plain-javascript version.

Answer (score 11):

You can also use the property `disable` to make the input **unusable and unclickable**. I think it's more clear and efficient way.

Here is the the difference between `readonly` and `disable`:

```html
<div>
  <input disabled type="text">
  <input readonly type="text">
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: Simple and efficient. I am constantly using this technique in production.

Answer (score 5):

Call the blur event when input is focused.

```
<input readonly onfocus="this.blur">
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a much better solution to your problem :)

Assuming you have an input field as :`<input type = "text" id = "textfield" >`

You need to modify 2 things,
1:
Your HTML declaration should be like :`<input type = "text" id = "textfield" readonly>`
2:
Go to your css and add the following lines of code

```
#textfield:hover{
cursor:default;
}
#textfield:focus{
cursor:default;
outline:none;
}
```

Explanation: It'll still be clickable but we are removing any default style changes happening due to click event to none. i.e. a white border which appears is manually removed. Therefore you can pretty much simulate the effect that nothing is being clicked.